# (u)platex and line indentation (tbook)

Tags: platex, uplatex

I'm using the tbook class to write text in Japanese. The problem is that text is not aligned the same for each line. This is easily observed using the quotation mark (「quote」) .

[image: Alignment issue]

Note that the text is vertically aligned from right to left.

The minimal example for this:

```
\documentclass{tbook}

\begin{document}

「

「あ、あ、あ、あ、あ、あ、あ、あ、あ、あ、あ、あ、あ、あ、あ、あ、あ、あ、あ、
あ、あ、あ、あ、あ、あ、あ、あ、あ、あ、あ、あ、あ、あ

\end{document}
```

Any ideas?

Edit: Filling stuff after the first "「" doesn't affect things. However, I did need to add a certain amount of "あ、"'s before the effect kicked in.

Update: This problem affects uplatex as well. Replace first line with `\documentclass[uplatex]{utbook}`.

Comment: i haven't used ptex, but i suspect the fact that the quote mark isn't followed by anything is what is causing the difference in position.  add a `\phantom{...}` after it and see if that helps.

Comment: @barbarabeeton I just wanted to make it as minimal as possible: Replacing "「" with "「orgij ae0g9j ea-gkr e[a9wakf 0ew9j0aj」" gives the exact same issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not surprising that `tbook.cls` has some flaws, because it is an old class file included in `jclasses`.

Instead, [`jsclasses`](https://oku.edu.mie-u.ac.jp/~okumura/jsclasses/), new standard Japanese class files created by Haruhiko Okumura, are now widely used for Japanese typesetting. `jsclasses` are better tuned than `jclasses`.

However, `jsclasses` does not contain any class files for vertical writing.
So when I make vertical-writing Japanese documents, I use `jsarticle.cls` or `jsbook.cls` with adjusting them to vertical-writing.

[This](https://www.overleaf.com/read/qkvrbgzqrmrv) is an example. I hope this helps.

Comment: It does address the problem perfectly! The new classes do not have the flaws mentioned. I had no idea I could swap to vertical writing for the horiz classes.